# Defining React Router routes within a separate component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

**The Problem:**

We have an application which defines it's own routes and components (e.g. Home, About Us, etc) but also consumes an internal NPM package called Basket.

The issue is the Basket component has multiple *steps* (e.g. User Details, Payment etc) and we plan on utilising React Router v6 to handle navigation between each step.

After reading the docs and browsing Stack', the standard approach is this:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/basket">
      <Route path="/user-details" element={<PaymentDetails />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The problem is we can't define it like that as Basket is to be used in multiple applications and maintaining it should be as simple as doing `npm install package@latest`.

**Questions:**

How can we achieve this as the following does not work and results in this error?

> `[Basket] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Basket countryCode="GB" />    
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

```js
export const Basket = ({
  countryCode,
}: BasketProps) => (
  // Attempted the following line as a Route and Fragment with both resulting in the attached error
  <Route path="/basket">
    <Route
      path="/mobile-capture"
      element={<UserDetails countryCode={countryCode} />}
    />
    // ... All other components
  </Route>
);
```

**Sidenote:**

The only way I've managed to get this working is with the following but it doesn't feel right for a few reasons (namely using multiple `<Routes />` isn't documented anywhere)

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>
  <Routes>
    <Basket countryCode="GB" />    
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

```js
export const Basket = ({
  countryCode,
}: BasketProps) => (
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/user-details-capture"
      element={<UserDetails countryCode={countryCode} />}
    />
    // ... All other components
  </Routes>
);
```

Comment: The error says only `<Route` can be children of React `<Routes`. Now the question is what do you want to maintain seperately. Have you considered, keeping just a config map seperately and having the `<Route>` related code in your client apps itself

Comment: What we are trying to 'maintain' is the ability to add, remove or modify the steps without having to do the same changes across several applications. This is why we are grouping them into one component rather than defining the routes at the component level.

You've raised an interesting point about having a config map which handles the setup then I can have the underlying solution iterate over the routes. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: FWIW, using multiple routes also should not be a problem. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes . All should signify multiple here i am assuming :D

Comment: Agreed, shouldn't be a problem but did spot some weirdness stating the base route couldn't be found (probably because it wasn't defined in the Basket area). Either way, thanks for ideas and solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multiple `Routes` is not a problem. You do have `<Routes>` in both places (your basket file and router file). I would suggest using an element also if possible.

```
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/basket/*" element={<Basket />} />
      <Route path="/bucket/*" element={<Bucket />} />
    </Routes>
```

and inside your `Basket` or `Bucket` component you can do:

```
const Basket = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/mobile-capture" element={<X />} />
      <Route path="/mobile-capture2" element={<Y />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Docs and discussions that suggest `Routes` is cool:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/9841

`<Routes>` will just provide a context for matching sub routes it seems.